# Updating Choice column's available values in Library settings automatically

Tags: list, flow, choice-field

In SharePoint Online, I have a choice column with "Check box" type and Fill-in choices allowed.

When the user enters a Fill-in choice, it should be automatically updated to the choice column as an available choice.

For Example:

Consider I have a column named "City" which is a choice column with "Check box" type and allows Fill-in choices.

Now, a user creates/updates an item, couldn't find his city in the choices and uses the Fill-in text box and enters, for example, "Florida"

Now, I want this "Florida" to be updated into "City" column's choices automatically.

Is this possible? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a managed metadata column for this requirement. Using an open term set, users can fill in their own choices which are then added to the term set (and can therefore be used by other users). The column would need to be created with the "Allow Fill-in" setting enabled.

If you are using SharePoint Online, there is the option of using the "Location" column for storing location data. So, for that specific example the location column would be better suited than using a managed metadata column.